# Как распарсить и вывести таблицу?

Tags: массивы, php, синтаксический-анализ

Привет, 
помогите, пожалуйста, распарсить массив (PHP), вывести в таблицу:

```
Название | Цена1 | Цена2
--------------------------
Продукт1 | 2,00   | 3,00
Продукт2 |        | 4,00
Продукт3 | 3,00   |
```

В базе  лежит так:

```
Продукт1; 2,00; Цена1;
Продукт1; 3,00; Цена2;
Продукт2; 2,00; Цена2;
Продукт3; 2,00; Цена1;
```

запрос из базы данных, в массиве.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

[@xBCAAx](/users/13765/xbcaax) дело говорит. 
Должны быть:

1. таблица товаров
2. таблица типов цен
3. таблица с ценами (похожая на вашу), в ней должны быть id товара, id типа цены и собственно цена

Дальше выбираете список цен, бежите по нему в цикле и формируете запрос. В итоге получаете:

```
select p.id, p.title,
  pr1.price as price1,
  pr2.price as price2,
  pr3.price as price3
from products p
  left join prices pr1 on p.id=pr1.product_id and pr1.price_id=1
  left join prices pr2 on p.id=pr2.product_id and pr2.price_id=2
  left join prices pr3 on p.id=pr3.product_id and pr3.price_id=3
```

что как раз и даст вашу табличку.

[пример структуры на sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9b9811/2)

Comment: не даст динамически(без изменения запроса) добавить новый тип цены, или запрос нужно переделать(лучше сделать несколько запросов)

Comment: @ToRcH565 да, запрос формируется каждый раз. это паттерн [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity–attribute–value_model). Удобство в том, что структура таблиц не меняется при добавлении типов цен, но появляются накладные расходы на формирование запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Не лучше привести таблицу к такому виду

```
id|product|price1|price2
------------------------
n|Продукт1|2.00  |3.00
```

Но если вам плевать на принципы нормализации. То сам запрос:

```
SELECT  t1.item, t2.price price1,t1.price price2,t2.head head1, t1.head head2
FROM tst t1, tst t2 
WHERE t1.item=t2.item AND t1.head<>t2.head GROUP BY item
```

Далее уже в фориче заносите в таблицу

Comment: Спасибо большое! нет не плевать, просто кол-во цен всегда разное и зависит от категории продукта. 

сделать в базе три колонки с ценой, а завтра надо будет четыре цены, тогда снова в базе настраивать?

Comment: Этот запрос именно под вашу ситуацию, эдакий костыль. Если вы добавите цену3, то и запрос надо другой.
Если в дальнейшем хотите добавить третюю цену, четверту, н-ю. Делайте две таблицы в одной айди продукта и имя продукта. Во второй айди продукта и цена.

Comment: тогда стоит пересмотреть способ вывода. и если вам нужна именно таблица то делать несколькими запросами, 

    1. выбрать максимальное кол-во цен для всех товаров
    2. выбрать уникальные товары.
    3. выбирать и выводить каждый товар и цены к нему, если цены закончились а строка таблици незаполнена - заполнять пустыми колонками.

Comment: именно так и сделал... сделал запрос и получил массив: 

Array ( [0] => 1 [id] =>1 [1] => Продукт1 [NAME] => Продукт1 [2] => 2.00 [PREIS] => 2.00 [3] => Цена1 [SIZEID] => Цена1 )
Array ( [0] => 2 [id] =>2 [1] => Продукт1 [NAME] => Продукт1 [2] => 3.00 [PREIS] => 3.00 [3] => Цена2 [SIZEID] => Цена2 )
Array ( [0] => 3 [id] =>3 [1] => Продукт2 [NAME] => Продукт2 [2] => 4.00 [PREIS] => 4.00 [3] => Цена2 [SIZEID] => Цена2 )
Array ( [0] => 4 [id] =>4 [1] => Продукт3 [NAME] => Продукт3 [2] => 2.00 [PREIS] => 2.00 [3] => Цена1 [SIZEID] => Цена1 )

теперь его пытаюсь правильно распарсить...